# multiple domains to have different page_on_front

Tags: wordpress

I have a number of domains pointing to my wordpress install... And everything works well.

Now, I would like to set the front page (page_on_front) to be different depending on the domain used. Ie.

http://www.site_A.com -> frontpage = page_A

http://www.site_B.com -> frontpage = page_B

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help. It is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the `$_SERVER` reserved variable in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) you can use the indices to check the URL and build a condition on it. In your case `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` should do it.

Example

```
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
// $url returns http://domain.name/path
```

If you have different domains forwarding to the same site and you want them to redirect, you could condition it so that when the domain name in the address bar matches a specific rule, then redirect.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='domainA.com') {
  // do something with domainA
} elseif($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='domainB.com') {
  // do something with domainB
} else {
  // do something with anything else
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need something else. I need to add an action or filter to the functions.php to set a different page from the option saved in meta_key page_on_front in the database. Or maybe if I find the right line, which is called get_option('page_on_front') in the core files, it can solve my problem. But I couldn't find it yet.